# What happens if I test Covid positive while staying in a German Hotel

Tags: germany, covid-19

I'm due to stay in a hotel for a couple of nights in a small hotel in Cologne before flying back to the UK. I now need to get a pre-departure Covid test. What happens if I test positive? The hotel may not want us to stay, and may not have room or even room service/facilities for us to isolate properly. The German rules seem to be that you have to isolate where you are but I'm not sure how that would work in this case.

Comment: My understanding is that you should continue to isolate where you are: https://www.zusammengegencorona.de/en/from-suspected-infection-to-isolation/

Whether or not your hotel does not have the facility to house you, I'd say you need to contact your travel insurance provider in the first instance, and the embassy/representation of your country in the second. The reason I say to contact your insurance provider first is that your travel insurance may be affected due to your infection: https://travelhealthpro.org.uk/news/499/novel-coronavirus-covid-19-general-advice-for-travellers

Comment: The [German Foreign Office](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/en/coronavirus/2317268) says "If travellers develop symptoms associated with COVID-19 ... they should get in touch by phone with a doctor or contact the hotline 116 117. Often travel guides or hotels can also help in such cases. Travellers should keep the contact details of their home country’s embassy or consulate in Germany in case they need to contact them." As to how hotels react, if they can't accommodate you, then you can't stay there, and you'll have to pay additional costs - exactly where you stay will be up to the state govt.

Answer (score 2):

Last I've heard was that you will have to report to the local Health Office or "Gesundheitsamt". They will manage this but as far as I can tell there is not a whole lot of consistency or predictability in the process.